# EF Core Domain Projection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, ef-core-2.0

Is there a performance difference between using a function inside a linq to sql select statement vs using an expression in EF core domain projection.

Ex.

```cs
context.Students.Select(x => StuddentDTOMapper(x)).ToList();
```

Vs.

```cs
context.Students.Select(StuddentDTOMapperExpression).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. But you can always check it on your own. I can tell you that you can gain a little performance boost by compiling your expressions. You can read about it more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/compiled-queries-linq-to-entities) and [here](https://cmatskas.com/improve-ef-core-performance-with-compiled-queries/).